Доступ к переменной в другом файле C++?
Есть три файла header.h, main.cpp, friend.cpp
Как получить доступ к переменной, которая находится в файле friend.cpp, если она мне нужна в main.cpp?

https://microsin.net/programming/arm-troubleshooting-faq/how-use-extern.html
